# MySQL Sub-query.. Doesn't provide proper information after 3 entries into table

Tags: sql, mysql

After I get 3 rows in my `forum_threads` table this no longer does it's job. Which is to organize a list of active forum threads and put the most recently responded-to thread at the top of the list, followed by second most recent posted-to thread, followed by third, fourth, etc.

Like I said, the query works wonders up until there is a fourth row added to `forum_threads`.

```
SELECT 
  forum_threads.*, 
  forum_posts.thread_id 
FROM 
  forum_threads 
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(id) AS id, thread_id as thread_id 
        FROM forum_posts 
    GROUP BY thread_id 
    ORDER BY id DESC
  ) forum_posts ON forum_threads.id = forum_posts.thread_id
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer does it's job"? Does it not return all the rows?

Answer (score 1):

On first glance your query looks okay. Sometimes it helps to try the same thing differently to spot an error, so check what the following gives you:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM forum_posts WHERE thread_id = t.id) max_post_id, 
  t.id
FROM 
  forum_threads t
ORDER BY
  max_post_id DESC
```

Add a composite index to `forum_posts` over `(thread_id, id)`.

Comment: This could certainly work, though the SELECT clause would need `t.id as thread_id, t.*` to match the poster's original query.  It might also be slower than the subquery join, but not obviously so; benchmarks on real data would be in order.

Comment: You are correct regarding the column name. Copy/paste error, I'll fix it. If there is an index in place, I'd expect negligible performance loss at worst.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be relying on MySQL to order the outer query in the same order as the inner query, without actually specifying what you want.  Try moving the ORDER BY clause to the outer query:

```
SELECT 
  forum_threads.*, 
  forum_posts.thread_id 
FROM 
  forum_threads 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id, thread_id as thread_id 
      FROM forum_posts 
    GROUP BY thread_id 
  ) forum_posts ON forum_threads.id = forum_posts.thread_id
ORDER BY forum_posts.id DESC
```